# Nativescript mapbox custom marker tooltip

Tags: mapbox, nativescript, marker

I am using mapbox in nativescript, how we can add a custom view (HTML or XML) to the marker tooltip.

Markers show only title and subtitle, I need to view my own layout instead

```
map.addMarkers([{
    lat: 52.3602160,
    lng: 4.8891680,
    title: 'marker title',
    subtitle: 'marker subtitle',
    image: 'https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8571/15844010757_63b093d527_n.jpg'
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

According [to the plugin README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-mapbox) you can add you own icons for the markers via **icon** and **iconPath**

```
  var onTap = function(marker) {
    console.log("Marker tapped with title: '" + marker.title + "'");
  };
  var onCalloutTap = function(marker) {
    alert("Marker callout tapped with title: '" + marker.title + "'");
  };

  mapbox.addMarkers([
    {
      id: 2, // can be user in 'removeMarkers()'
      lat: 52.3602160, // mandatory
      lng: 4.8891680, // mandatory
      title: 'One-line title here', // no popup unless set
      subtitle: 'Infamous subtitle!',
      icon: 'res://cool_marker', // preferred way, otherwise use:
      icon: 'http(s)://website/coolimage.png', // from the internet (see the note at the bottom of this readme), or:
      iconPath: 'res/markers/home_marker.png',
      onTap: onTap,
      onCalloutTap: onCalloutTap
    },
    {
      ..
    }
  ])
```

There is also the [official demo](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-mapbox-demo/blob/02cc921e11a1a6e84663c22bfdd4b6f5864972aa/Mapbox/app/main-page.js#L18) which demonstrates how to use the icons for markers